# Many to Many Laravel 4 with string based primary key

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Given a few models trying to use Contact::sync(array(1,2,3)) to add mailing lists fails because the primary key email_address does not get filled out.

The table structure:

```
Contacts
    - email_address string (PK)
    - name          string

MailingLists
    - id    integer (PK)
    - name  string

ContactMailingLists
    - contact_id      string (PK, FK)
    - mailing_list_id integer (PK, FK)
```

And Models:

```
<?php

class MailingList extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'mailing_lists';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function contacts ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Application\Entity\Contact', null, 'id', 'email_address')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Contact extends Eloquent 
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'contacts';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'email_address';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function mailing_lists ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Application\Entity\MailingList', null, 'id', 'mailing_list_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

When using ->sync() or other relational functions in eloquent it produces errors. The sync() method produces an error because on the insert the email_address is set to 0 instead of the email_address.

**EDIT:** Added the related keys to the code.

Comment: @Shawn, I don't have the exact error in front of me, but it came up in the form of a foreign key constraint error because the insert into the pivot table has email_address set as 0 due to the $incrementing setting.

Answer (score 2):

Set the models to no longer attempt to auto increment the primary key.

Add this on any models that don't have an auto incrementing key (such as email_address).

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `custom key` when declaring the relation along with the `pivot table` name:

```
public function mailing_lists ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\Application\Entity\MailingList', 'ContactMailingLists', 'email_address', 'MailingList_id')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Check [the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that when creating the example. I've added them in for this case.